# Need help to build an EF query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can't find the correct way to build an EF (4.1) query that will return the same result as this SQL containing a LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT
    s.id_service,
    s.description,
    x.id_service as isDisponible
FROM
    role.service_disponible s
LEFT JOIN
    role.service_disponible_x_ue x
ON s.id_service = x.id_service AND x.id_ue = 1 and flg_actif = '1'
```

In fact I'm just trying to obtain the complete list of services disponible (ServiceDisponible) adding a field that tell me if service is disponible for a specific entity (filtered with the id_ue) which information come from a many to many related table (ServiceDisponibleXUe).

My model is:

[image]

Ideally, I would like this query to return this viewModel object what is basically my serviceDisponible domain with one more field indicating the disponibility of the service.

```cs
public ServiceDisponibleViewModel(ServiceDisponible ServiceDisponible, bool isDisponible)
{
    this.serviceDisponible = serviceDisponible;
    this.isDisponible = isDisponible;
}
```

What I have so far is this query but the syntax is invalid:

```
services = context.ServiceDisponible
                  .Select(a => new ServiceDisponibleViewModel
                  {
                    c => new ServiceDisponible
                          {
                            id_service = a.id_service,
                            description = a.description
                          },
                    isDisponible = a.ServiceDisponibleXUe
                                   .Any(b => b.flg_actif && b.id_ue == idUe)
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ServiceDisponibleViewModel services = 
        from sd  in context.ServiceDisponible
        from sdx in context.ServiceDisponibleXUe
                           .Where(x => x.id_ue == 1 && flg_actif == '1' && x.id_service == sd.id_service)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new ServiceDisponibleViewModel(
            new ServiceDisponible
            {
            id_service = sd.id_service,
            description = sd.description
            },
            sdx.id_service
        );
```

Comment: Is it possible to return an object of type ServiceDisponibleViewModel instead of an anonymous class?

Comment: It seems that we can't use anything else than anonymous class... the query give me the error: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Answer (score 0):

Having SQL as example often makes one jump to a join in linq. But using navigation properties produces much more succinct syntax:

```
from sd  in context.ServiceDisponible
from sdx in sd.ServiceDisponibleXUes.Where(x => x.id_ue == 1 
                                             && x.flg_actif == "1")
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{   sd.id_service,
    sd.description,
    isDisponible = sdx.id_service
};
```

(I couldn't help using the plural form of `ServiceDisponibleXUe` which imo is more clear).